# Getting QueryResultIterable not found error with Gradle appengine project using Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, build.gradle

I've set up an Gradle App Engine project and ported over my code that was working perfectly well. But on building the project through Gradle I get the following error:

```
20:28:32.036 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler] Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
20:28:32.088 [ERROR] [system.err] D:\Projects\WordBuzzIntegrated\wordbuzzserver\src\com\wrc\wordbuzzweb\service\Login.java:21: error: cannot access QueryResultIterable
20:28:32.088 [ERROR] [system.err]         User user = ofy().load().type(User.class).id(facebookUser.id).now();
20:28:32.089 [ERROR] [system.err]                                 ^
20:28:32.089 [ERROR] [system.err]   class file for com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIterable not found
```

I don't really have a clue what's causing the problem and Googling the error returns zero results. My dependencies list is as follows:

```
  dependencies {
        appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.15'
        providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.3'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.3'
        compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.1'
    }
```

If anyone has any idea what might be going on here then your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other App Engine dependencies that need to be included in the Gradle build. I ended up including all of the following for good measure - although I'm not sure all are required:

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk "com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:$appEngineVersion"
    compile "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:$appEngineVersion"
    compile "com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:$appEngineVersion"
    compile "com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:$appEngineVersion"

    compile "com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.1"
    compile group: "com.google.guava", name: "guava", version: "18.0"
}
```

If using IntelliJ be sure to add the jars to your artifact for deployment.

If you want to run unit tests (junit included below) then you'll also need to add the following

```
    testCompile group: "junit", name: "junit", version: "4.11"
    testCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:$appEngineVersion"
    testCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:$appEngineVersion"
    testCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:$appEngineVersion"
```

You'll also need to include the following in your Gradle script to set the app engine version. (Check what the latest version is)

```
ext.appEngineVersion = '1.9.21'
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem can be solved by adding the following dependendy in Gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.21'
```

You do not need to have the dependency for Cloud Endpoints if you are not using it, although it will also solve the problem as it has itself a dependeny on the missing one.

Ran into the same issue when generating a module with Android Studio which did not include this API. I could not even find any information on it in the documentation.